# Moving files over SSH and delete on source after successful final copy

Tags: command-line, ssh, rsync

I have a folder of ~200 000 files with a total size around 300 GB that I need to transfer over an SSH connection to a remote host. I'm looking for a way to have the local files deleted after it's been verified that they've been successfully copied to the remote host, but I can't figure out how to do it. `rsync --remove-source-files` seems unsafe if connection breaks according to other posts ([here](https://superuser.com/questions/405761/rsync-remove-source-files-deletes-source-files-one-by-one-or-after-rsync-compl)). How can it be done safely?

Comment: What about `rsync $arguments && rm -r $folder`? That should invoke `rsync`, and only run the `rm` if `rsync` exits successfully.

Comment: I need the files to be removed during the transfer, after each individual file (or a small number of files) has been copied. (The reason for this simply being that I need space on the local drive and that the connection I'm copying over is annoyingly slow.)

Comment: Might you split the files up into subdirectories, then `rsync` one subdir at a time, removing it on successful upload? (Do you need the solution to be automated, or will you be more or less at your computer the entire time?)

Comment: I need to keep the folder structure, so I can't make subfolders. I would prefer it to be automated. Basically `rsync --remove-source-files` but more stable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Have a shell script:**
*Note that it makes some assumptions, which I've documented below.*

```
#!/bin/sh

# first, upload the directory structure
# be REALLY sure that it made it intact!
while true
do
    # try to upload it:
    rsync $flags --filter="+ */" --filter="- *" $source $destination
    # it uploaded fine? cool, break the loop (else try again):
    [ "$?" -eq 0 ] && break
done

# now the files
for file in $(find $source -not -type d)
do
    # again, be REALLY sure they copied okay!
    while true
    do
        # try to upload it:
        rsync $flags $file $destination/$file
        # it uploaded fine? cool, break the innermost loop (else try again):
        [ "$?" -eq 0 ] && break
    done
    # delete the local copy of the file:
    rm $file
done
```

**This script assumes the following:**

1. That `$source`, `$destination`, and `$flags` were either set as environment variables, or replaced in the script with the actual source, destination, and any other `rsync` flags you want used. (Don't replace `$?` or `$file`.)
2. That `$source` is be a relative path.
3. That `rsync` will exit with a nonzero status if *for any reason* the specified `$file` was not copied 100% successfully.
4. **That you've tested it on less important data, because I haven't.**

---

The `rsync` `--filter` parameters were copied from [a blog post](http://psung.blogspot.de/2008/05/copying-directory-trees-with-rsync.html) by [some guy called Phil](http://www.blogger.com/profile/12760478278391942483). I hope that's okay with him. :)

Comment: Cool, thanks. If I understand the script, it will create a new connection for each file - won't that slow down the transfer substantially? Though, I guess if it gets the job done it's worth it anyway :)

Comment: You're absolutely right—it will use a new instance of `rsync` for each file, preventing connection reuse. I can't think of another way to get the files deleted as soon as they're done uploading, though, except maybe using `strace` or something, and deleting files as `rsync` closes them?

Comment: You might combine my script with Kent's solution. Instead of making a list of all the files and copying them one by one, make a list of subdirectories with a few files in each (you can be the judge of how many to upload at a time). Again, test it out with less important things, first; I'm not sure how `rsync foo/bar $server:foo/bar` behaves with an existing `foo/bar` directory on the server—it might copy the local `foo/bar` to _inside_ the remote one, giving you `foo/bar/bar` and breaking your directory structure!

Comment: You can work around the latter problem by assuming there are no duplicates in the directory list and deleting the empty folders (`ssh $server rm -r $destination/$file`) before you call `rsync`. That does introduce more overhead, though. Grrrrr… (I hope you have passwordless `ssh` login set up, too. Needless to say, this will require logging into the server many, _many_ times.)

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html). sshfs lets you "mount" a remote directory via ssh (actually performing commands other ssh to mimick a file system). You can then use `mv` to move your files.

You don't need to be superuser, since it's a userspace filesystem.

Comment: How does `mv` handle broken connections?

Comment: Isn't `sshfs` somewhat unreliable? I'm guessing Morgan wants `rsync` for its verification (else a simple `scp -r $folder $host:$folder` would suffice), and if that's the case, I wouldn't want to use `sshfs`. (The alternative would be using `rsync` over `sshfs`, defeating the purpose of using `sshfs` in the first place.)

Comment: If the source and destination are both on the same filesystem, the link to the file is modified.  If the file is on a different filesystem, the file is first copied and the original file has its link removed.  If the connection breaks before the file is copied, you may potentially have a partial file, but the original would be left alone.

Comment: @Blacklight Shining: depends on what you call unreliable (we use it on a daily basis). The point is that if you let the connection inactive for some time, one endpoint (either client or server) may decide to close the connection. If you perform a sshfs / mv (or cp) / fuserumount, there won't be any trouble, since the connection is always used. If you perform an sshfs in the morning and expect the connection to be up say an hour later, you have to be sure your sshd and possibly the client are configured so that the connection is maintained up.

Comment: @user2783897 It wasn't inactivity-related, but I remember someone saying using `sshfs` was inadvisable for reasons of instability|unreliability.

Comment: I don't know if I didn't understand or if it wasn't answered, but what would happen if I do `mv` and my connection breaks (for whatever reason I can't control). Will that break the file currently being transferred?

Comment: Hi Morgan. UtahJarhead answered: if the connection breaks for any reason during file transfer, you'll have a partially transfered file on the receiving side, and your file intact on the sending side (since file on the sending side is only deleted after the transfer).

Comment: If you're using sshfs, you can help prevent random disconnects due to idle timeouts by using ServerAliveInterval on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the files up into blocks of ten for example, and then

```
rsync (source files) destination
```

And, if it ran successfully, follow it with

```
rsync --remove-source-files (source files) destination
```

The added bandwidth of a second rsync command is negligible.

Comment: No need to run `rsync` again; it'd just waste time checking to make sure that the files are all the same—which it just did, in the first invocation. After `rsync`, you can just do `rm -r $source_files`.

Comment: Doh! Good point.  I got caught up in the `rsync` euphoria.  It -may- provide a slightly larger sense of security, in that the second rsync checks the work of the first one... but, I think that would be minimal at best.